# Need help converting integer reliant method to use BigInteger instead

Tags: java, methods, biginteger

I want to replace all integers in the following block of code with BigIntegers (checks if a number is prime and returns true/false):

```
    static boolean primeCheck(long n) {
        if (n <= 1) {
            return false;
        }
        for (long i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

This obviously works perfectly with integers, but with BigIntegers, this is how far I got until I gave up:

```
    static boolean check(BigInteger n) {
        BigInteger lessThanOne;
        lessThanOne = n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE);
        if (lessThanOne.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) <= 0) {
            return false;
        } for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
                i.compareTo(n) < 0;
                i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            BigInteger result = n.mod(i);
            if (result.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Could use some help with this.

Comment: You gave up because? Whats the problem? Also I don't understand why you have `lessThanOne`, isn't `if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(2)) < 0)` enough?

Comment: better yet, why using `BigInteger`? this will be a bit more expensive to calculate depending on what you're doing. Since you're checking primes, any performance you can squeeze from it the better. BigInteger will expand with a needed number of `long` values to fit your number.

Answer (score 0):

lessThanOne is a mistake here. Just judge n.compareTo(1) is ok.

```
static boolean check(BigInteger n) {
    //BigInteger lessThanOne = BigInteger.ONE;
    //lessThanOne = n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE);
    if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(2); i.compareTo(n) < 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        BigInteger result = n.mod(i);
        if (result.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```